# No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found

Tags: c#, wpf, memorystream

Herein is my piece of code but I've got an error

> **No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found**

in "**EndInit()**" line.

I've read WIC registry modification (NB: my OS is Windows 7 and my IDE is VS 2010) but it did not work at all :(

I was wondering if you let me know what do I do to solve it.

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();


byte[] DM = new byte[307200];

for (int i = 0; i < 640; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
        if (i < 500)
            DM[i + j] = i;

using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(DM))
{
    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
    myBitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 640;
    myBitmapImage.EndInit();

}

img.Source = myBitmapImage;
```

Comment: Just for Google: The German translation of this error is "**Es wurde keine passende Imagingkomponente zum Abschließen dieses Vorgangs gefunden.**".

Comment: @Uwe Keim, you better use: http://unlocalize.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you cannot just pass in an array of pixel data; there is no way the class can know what length and height, what channels and what color depth the image is supposed to have. You need to provide a valid header for the supported formats, e.g. bmp, jpg or png. There are some others, a listing exists somewhere on MSDN.

Since you want to create a bitmap from scratch you might want to use a [`WritableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) instead.

*(By the way, [`DecodePixelWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth.aspx) does not what you presumably think it does; it just scales the picture down after decoding it to save memory)*